# Error when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: java, android, flutter

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I tried also JDK 11 but it doesn't works.
How do I fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling us that our class was compiled at a higher version of Java than the version with which we tried to run it. More specifically, in this case we compiled our class with Java 11 and tried to run it with Java 8.

we have two ways we can resolve this error: compile our code for an earlier version of Java, or run our code on a newer Java version.

I think this website might help you https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem

1. del
   [Two folders and delete backup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr1Jd.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etv60.png)
2. restart
3. Modify the java_home java11
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   SUCCESS;

> my idea
> flutter doctor -v
> Found that he is the android jre in the studio,
> Switch the Java version has no effect
> Has been submitted to the error in this, and then think of first take the Android's studio
> After the restart switch to java11 javahome path
> Performed again 'flutter doctor --android-licenses'
> SUCCESS!
> happy(Do not rule out is my operational problems, this is my solution, hope to bring help, welcome to correct me, thank you!)
> Can't find the android download manager can check the latest
> [tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEknm.png)

Comment: Please supplement your images with text and mention the name of the folders to delete. Furthermore the screenshot of the Android SDK would need a description as it is unclear what to do with it.

Comment: You can click on the text with underscores to see the questions that need to be deleted. Additionally, what needs to be removed is (jbr and jre under studio).